# Rotate a PGF figure, and being able to center it

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, pdftex, rotating

I have a figure, created in MS Visio, a PDF figure. I have added text to the figure using `qtix`. The code is pasted below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.30]
\pgftext{\includegraphics{TransformerSubstationFeeding}}

\small

\node at (8,-0.5) {Ground};
\node at (-0.5,-0.5) {Ground};
\node at (-9,-0.5) {Ground};

\node at (14.5,9.1) {Public grid; phase A};
\node at (14.5,8.3) {phase A};
\node at (14.5,7.5) {phase B};
\node at (14.5,6.7) {phase C};

\node at (14.5,2.3) {Railway grid};
\node at (14.5,1.5) {catenary};
\node at (14.5,0.7) {rail/ground};

\node at (11.5,3.8) {Transformer};
\node at (3.0,3.8) {Transformer};
\node at (-5.5,3.8) {Transformer};

\end{tikzpicture}
```

The figure is more landscape-shaped, so I want to rotate the figure in my document. The figure is attached below. [image]

The problem is I dot now know how to rotate figures that are inserted by the `\input` command. The `\includegraphics` command can use rotation, but then each text also need to be rotated. And when doing that, the centering of the image fails. I have tried that too. See the code below:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[rotate=90,scale=0.32]
\pgftext{\includegraphics{TransformerSubstationFeeding}}

\small

\node[rotate=90] at (8,-0.5) {Ground};
\node[rotate=90] at (-0.5,-0.5) {Ground};
\node[rotate=90] at (-9,-0.5) {Ground};

\node[rotate=90] at (14.5,9.1) {Public grid; phase A};
\node[rotate=90] at (14.5,8.3) {phase A};
\node[rotate=90] at (14.5,7.5) {phase B};
\node[rotate=90] at (14.5,6.7) {phase C};

\node[rotate=90] at (14.5,2.3) {Railway grid};
\node[rotate=90] at (14.5,1.5) {catenary};
\node[rotate=90] at (14.5,0.7) {rail/ground};

\node[rotate=90] at (11.5,3.8) {Transformer};
\node[rotate=90] at (3.0,3.8) {Transformer};
\node[rotate=90] at (-5.5,3.8) {Transformer};


\end{tikzpicture}
```

The main document part of my code looks like:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \input{Visioritning2.pgf}
    \caption{A simplified illustration of how the three-phase grid commonly feeds the railway when using substation transformers}
    \label{Figure:SimplifiedTransformerSubstation}
\end{figure}
```

So any suggestions of what I should do? The main problem is:

- How to both rotate and center a PGF-created PDF-based figure with added explanatory text on it?
- Is it preferable to to the rotation in PGF-code or is it better to do it in the, or before the `\input` statement?

Comment: Hi Lars, welcome to TeX.sx! I've edited your question a bit: Inline code snippets can be formatted by enclosing them in backticks (or selecting them and clicking the `{}` button). I've also inserted your image, and removed the closing, to keep with the format of this site.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your needs correctly. General material (text and/or images) can be rotated using `\rotatebox{<angle>}{<content>}` from the `graphicx` package (already loaded by `tikz`). `\centering` should center it, at least relative to its official size. Try to avoid having whitespace around your real content. You should crop the PDF first using `pdfcrop` for example.

Comment: This looks also like a good usecase of `standalone`. The v1.0 version provides `\includestandalone[<options, incl. angle>]{<code file, like your .pgf>}`.

Comment: @MartinScharrer: I think this is an answer ;-)

Answer (score 5):

You can rotate general material, like your whole picture, using the `\rotatebox{<angle>}{<content>}` macro from the standard `graphicx` package (already loaded by TikZ anyway), e.g. try `\rotatebox{90}{\input{<filename>}}`.

This looks also like a good use-case of `standalone`. The v1.0 version provides `\includestandalone[<options, incl. angle>]{<code file, like your .pgf>}`.
This also allows you to compile the picture on its own, which is very nice during its creation process.

---

```
% Visioritning2.tex
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.30]
\pgftext{\includegraphics{TransformerSubstationFeeding}}

\small

\node at (8,-0.5) {Ground};
\node at (-0.5,-0.5) {Ground};
\node at (-9,-0.5) {Ground};

\node at (14.5,9.1) {Public grid; phase A};
\node at (14.5,8.3) {phase A};
\node at (14.5,7.5) {phase B};
\node at (14.5,6.7) {phase C};

\node at (14.5,2.3) {Railway grid};
\node at (14.5,1.5) {catenary};
\node at (14.5,0.7) {rail/ground};

\node at (11.5,3.8) {Transformer};
\node at (3.0,3.8) {Transformer};
\node at (-5.5,3.8) {Transformer};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

```
% Main document
\documentclass{article}% or any other
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{standalone}
\begin{document}
% ...
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includestandalone[angle=90]{Visioritning2}
    \caption{A simplified illustration of how the three-phase grid commonly feeds the railway when using substation transformers}
    \label{Figure:SimplifiedTransformerSubstation}
\end{figure}
% ...
\end{document}
```